# HTML5 Canvas API with php

Tags: javascript, php, canvas, html5-canvas

I use a JS script to generate a 2D image in a `<canvas>` using [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API) according to a set of parameters.

In order to save this image on the server, I don't want to send the generated image by the browser, I would like to send only the parameters and redraw the image directly on the server using PHP if possible.

The js script is quite complex, and I would like to use the same or very close syntax in php.

Do you know if there is a PHP class (or something else) that uses the canvas API syntax to generate images?

I guess the easiest way would be to use nodejs on the server...

Thanks for your advice

Comment: are you looking for something like these https://flaviocopes.com/canvas-node-generate-image/ source: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas

Comment: I prefer a solution in php
Thank you very much for your answer and the tip in case I use nodejs